# JavaScript get td from table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with tbodies. I want to create a array with the values in the first td of with tbody. How can I do that?

My html:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Val1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Val2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Val3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Val4</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My array should have the values: Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4

Comment: where is the javascript you have written to attempt to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `getElementsByTagName(tagName)` which returns an array of elements.

Something like this should work:

```
var array = []; //your array
var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");

for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    array[i] = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`$(selector).map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) at this context,

```
var x = $("#myTable > tbody > tr > td:first-child").map(function(){
  return this.textContent;
}).get().join();
console.log(x); //Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/e1b5zv1e/)

A pure javascript version by using `Array.prototype.map()` along with `querySelectorAll()`,

```
var x = [].map.bind(
  document.querySelectorAll("#myTable > tbody > tr > td:first-child"),function(elem){
     return elem.textContent;
})();
console.log(x); //Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/e1b5zv1e/1/)

Comment: @LuanSoares Addressed that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var bodies = document.getElementById("myTable").tBodies;
var items = [];

for (var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++)
  items.push(bodies[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerText);

alert(items);
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Val1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Val2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Val3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Val4</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with jQuery:

```js
var myArray=[];
$('#myTable tbody tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function(){
 myArray.push($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the native javascript `[Element].getElementsByTagName([TagName])[index]` method.

```
// Get the array of <tbody> elements in the document.
tbodies = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
values = [];

// Loop through the array of <tbody> elements.
for(var index = 0; index < tbodies.length; index++) {
    // Add the value of the <td> element to the array of values.
    values += tbodies[index].firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
}
```

The line `values += tbodies[index].firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue` gets each `<tbody>` element and finds it's `firstChild` (the `<tr>` element) and finds the `<tr>` element's `firstChild` (the `<td>` element) and then finds the text that it contains (`.nodeValue`).

The `values` array ends up with resulting value of `["Val1","Val2","Val3","Val4"]`.